# Deep learning for Non Image binary classification data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm

I am a beginner in Deep learning, I have a data set that contains patients' data (with categorical and numerical features (231 features in total)) and we need to classify if the patients have an "ABC" disease or not (a binary classification problem), currently, I have used a normal feed-forward NN and performed hyperparameter tuning (Activation functions, layers/neurons, optimizers etc). Now, for the comparison, I have to use a deep learning architecture that overcomes vanishing/exploding gradient problems in deep learning. I have not found anything which can be useful in my scenario the examples I have found are based on image data.
Can we use Resnets, CNN, LSTM (I know this is used for sequence problems)? If we can use any of them, can you please provide a good resource/tutorial which can be a good starting point for my learning?
Or if there is any other way to work with them please let me know.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: How big is this dataset? Apriori GBM are extremely successful when dealing with tabular data, DNNs are not

Comment: Thank you for the response, the dataset contains 1700 rows, I can understand that DNNs are not quite good for this kind of data but I have to try DNNs only for this project

Comment: OK, fair enough. Look at TabNet at first instance then. Also if this is a project/write-up I would go forward and explain why certain architecture (e.g. CNNs) do not lend themselves naturally to tabular data, i.e. data with no intrinsic ordering.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will look into TabNet!